# Easy way to close 4 contacts at the same time

Tags: button

I'm building a smartphone rig to check the smartphone camera quality, focus and shutter speed.

This is my RIG, I have 4 bluetooth remote paired and I solder to the buttons some wires. If I take a single couple of wires and I put them in contact the smartphone shoot a picture, but If I group the wires together they doesn't work.

I need to close the 4 couple of wires at the same times keeping them isolated one from each other. I cannot find a 4 way button.

Any solution?

[image]

Comment: measure whether the buttons are openers or closers, and figure out the "off state" voltage across the button. Then, probably, just use a transistor for each of the buttons.

Comment: by the way, it's surprising that grouping the wires doesn't work – as far as I can tell, these devices are battery operated and hence don't have a common reference voltage. Is there a reason you wired up the other button on your second-from-right device?

Comment: Yes, the are seen by the smartphone as keyboard buttons, one is for iOS devices and the others are for Android.

Comment: @MarcusMüller do you think this is 4 way? http://it.rs-online.com/web/p/interruttori-a-pulsante/4954434/

Comment: Have you check the datasheet to be sure?

Comment: Maybe you're powering these from a common supply or a row of mains chargers with an earthed -ve supply and that's makes isolated switches a necessity...? At any rate, can I recommend a 4-channel opto-isolator, such as Vishay SFH6916 for under £1. You can use one isolated output transistor per phone and connect the four drive LEDs all in series with a current limit resistor, then power that to trigger the phones.

Comment: Wiring them together with camera 2 on a different switch seems off. However, this seems like a lot of labor to hook up the test. If you are doing this for a lot of phones, you would probably be better with a more mechanical solution as part of the jig to actually press the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 15401 and 15451 from MEC seems to match with your need. Here is the datasheet :

http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/051b/0900766b8051b322.pdf

According to manufacturer website, 15401 is a momentary switch and 15451 a latching switch.

http://www.mec.dk/Unimec-v12-p-72.html#2

However, I couldn't find the part 15401 on any web site but RS Europe. 15451 is nowhere to be found...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for 4 pole 1 throw switch, and [4 pole double throw](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lot-of-4-ON-ON-4PDT-Miniature-Toggle-Switch-Four-Pole-Double-Throw-/122019719413) switch would work as well.
There are many options over there. Google [4pdt switch](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=4pdt%20switch&safe=strict&espv=2&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE5czeyorTAhUFuhoKHRcyBHUQ_AUIBSgA&biw=1366&bih=648&dpr=1) (4 pole double throw) for more resultes.

Answer (score 0):

I would have made this a comment, but still don't have that ability here yet, so this will depend on answers to a few questions I would have asked - namely regarding on-hand parts and availability. Also, allow me to disclaim this by saying: I know it is not as simple as a single 4-pole switch, but it's how I'd solve it with things I have immediately available, and at a cost below US$1. Your mileage may vary.

That being said... If you are comfortable with soldering (which it looks like you are), you can use a few components to create a 4-pole single throw momentary switch that *may* also cost less than a mechanical one. What you'll need:

- SPST "Normally Open" Momentary Pushbutton or Tactile Switch
- 10k Resistor (or close to that value)
- Breadboard, Perfboard or IC Prototyping Board
- Batteries & Connector (two to four AAs or AAAs, or one 9v)
- CD4066 Quad Bilateral Switch IC (pictured below)

[image: CD4066 Quad Bilateral Switch IC]

ICs may be intimidating to use if you are unfamiliar with them, but this solution really only relies on the ability to solder. The 4066 is basically just 4 on/off switches that are individually controlled by an applied voltage, instead of manually. Below, we will add a manual component to deliver the voltage.

1. IC Power: Connect your positive battery lead to pin 14, and the negative to pin 7.
2. Control Switch: Connect your positive battery lead to one terminal of your switch, and run 4 wires from the other terminal to the control pins (5, 6, 12, & 13) of your IC. You can also do this with a single wire to one control pin, and run jumpers to the other three.
3. Pulldown Resistor: Connect the 10k resistor between pin 5 *or* 6, and 7 (battery negative). It can work without this, but it's common practice.
4. Trigger Interface: Connect your trigger wire pairs to pins 1&2, 3&4, 8&9, and 10&11.

Whenever you press your control switch, you will activate all 4 switches on the chip - yielding a simultaneous triggering of all of the remotes.

EDIT: Here is a quick [video demonstration](https://youtu.be/mfwn_HZSTNM) of the circuit in operation.

Comment: I will try with the simple switch... if it doesn't work as I hope I will try this active solution.

Comment: the button is arrived today but it doesn't work as espected, so I'm following your advice now. Just a question: I measure 3v from every open contact, is it a problem with the IC?

Comment: 3v will work just fine. I built the circuit to confirm everything, and added a link to a video demonstration in the answer above.

Comment: @Roberto Pezzali Would you please explain more. why didn't the buttons work? Isn't it the solution that you were looking for?